# Nagios notification_interval for weekday vs weekend

Tags: nagios

I would like to configure Nagios to send a page once every 6 hours Monday through Friday, but only once every 24 hours Saturday & Sunday. I am having a hard time wrapping my mind around how to have one group of admins have two different paging frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how it could be done but I hope somebody has a better method. Define your service for weekdays:

```
define service{
    name                    foo-weekday
    host_name               linux-server
    service_description     check-disk-sda1-weekday
    check_command           check-disk!/dev/sda1
    max_check_attempts      5
    check_interval          5
    retry_interval          3
    check_period            weekday
    notification_interval   360
    notification_period     weekday
    notification_options    w,c,r
    contact_groups          linux-admins
    }
```

Then inherit from it, overriding the check_period, notification_interval, notification_period, and service_description (which must be unique per-host) for the weekend:

```
define service{
    name                    foo-weekend
    use                     foo-weekday
    service_description     check-disk-sda1-weekend
    check_period            weekend
    notification_interval   1440
    notification_period     weekend
    }
```

Edit: I wonder if user macros would work in this situation? E.g., only have 1 service definition:

```
define service{
    host_name               linux-server
    service_description     check-disk-sda1
    check_command           check-disk!/dev/sda1
    max_check_attempts      5
    check_interval          5
    retry_interval          3
    check_period            24x7
    notification_interval   $USER21$
    notification_period     24x7
    notification_options    w,c,r
    contact_groups          linux-admins
    }
```

Then, have two different resource files. One defines USER21 as "360" and one as "1440". When the weekend starts copy the latter in place and reload the nagios config. When the weekend ends copy the former into place and reload.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am digesting it all right now. The idea of the user macro came to me is a (slightly) different idea of just having cron switchout the services.cfg file on Friday at 5pm and then back to normal Monday at 9am. I like the idea of just changing the notification_interval even better

Comment: Hey @Mark, so I am trying to get the user macro working and having some trouble.

resources.cfg
$USER3$=/usr/local/nagios/etc/time.marcro

time.macro
1440

services.cfg
`
define host {
 name    generic-host
 max_check_attempts  5
 check_interval    5
 check_command   check_host_alive
 first_notification_delay 30
 notification_interval  $USER3$
 notification_period  24x7
 notification_options  d,r
 contact_groups   admins
}
`

Do you see any glaring errors?

Comment: Sorry the formatting is garbage.... clearly I'm doing something wrong trying to post that.

Comment: I never used a macro in that context so maybe it doesn't work. I do not use Nagios anymore so I can't test it.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up Mark. It might just be that I need to replace the whole services.cfg rather than doing it the (far more elegant) way you suggested.